# Is EF4 ObjectContext.SaveChanges thread safe?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, thread-safety, savechanges

I am accessing my database via Entity Framework 4.

I have a server that listens on a port, awaiting some messages. When a message comes, it is translated into a table row and it should be inserted into the database. However, multiple messages can come at once. For each message I create a Task (from TPL) and execute it asynchronously.

Each of these tasks creates an instance of the ObjectContext, creates an object of the appropriate entity class (represents a table in DB), inserts the data into the ObjectContext, and then calls the SaveChanges method.

Thus each thread created its own ObjectContext. 
Can an instance of the ObjectContext influence any other instance of the ObjectContext? 
Would this scenario have any side-effects?

(Note that the data inserted won't create any referential integrity error).

Comment: Do your rows have a timestamp column? If so, you might run into concurrency exceptions when working with different instances of ObjectContext. This doesn't answer your question about thread safety, but it is something that could cause an error.

Comment: I am not sure why would having a timestamp column cause an error. Care to elaborate in a word or two? They do have a timestamp column, but that is not in anyway related to EF, I guess EF should treat such column the same as any other column (which is not a key).

Comment: Sorry, since you are only doing inserts, it should not matter. However if there were any updates, consider this: context1 and context2 are both opened with timestamp1. Context1 saves, which updates to timestamp2. When Context2 goes to save, its timestamp1 will not match the newly read timestamp2, causing a concurrency exception to be thrown.

Comment: ok, that's expected. I am aware of that issue, but it's not a problem in my scenario, as you already noticed, I only insert the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your situation transactional integrity is guaranteed by the database (SQL Server) and not Entity Framework. Since each thread has its own context you don't have to worry about each context's `SaveChanges()` interfering with another.

One instance of `ObjectContext` can not influence another one. You may run into a situation where one `SaveChanges()` modifies the database in a way that causes a subsequent `SaveChanges()` on a different context to fail. But this is by design and, again, is a result of SQL Server enforcing its constraints.

Answer (score 1):

A data-context is not usually thread-safe; but because they are all independent (per-request) that is not an issue.

The overly simplistic answer is "no", in that the contexts are unrelated. However, anything talking to the database may have edge conditions, depending on what queries you run before the `SaveChanges`, and whether any turn out to be phantom or non-repeatable reads, or if anything is updating data that has *also* been updated by another request, or doing 2 inserts on different requests that *individually* would be fine, but in combination violate a unique constraint, etc.

Comment: But your side-effects are really caused by the database - not EF. Am I correct understanding what you meant here?

Comment: so basically EF performs only SQL queries needed to change the DB state from the one defined by the data currently loaded and the one at the moment of calling SaveChanges(). And if such changes can be made without SQL server causing an error, EF will succeed (connection or other problems put aside)... Is that correct?

Comment: Yes; as long as the db doesn't complain, and you don't have any *other* unsafe thing you haven't mentioned - then EF in separate contexts won't cause a problem.